# D3 arc gradient

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, gradient

I'm trying to create a timer using d3 which has a gradient which will change between 0 and 100%. For example dark orange at 0% and light orange at 100%. I can make the arc transition between dark and light orange but having problems finding anything which allows me to apply a gradient to the arc. An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Been searching/frying my brain trying to achieve this for a day or so now.

Comment: There are lots of questions here on how to use gradients with SVG and D3, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826604/how-to-use-svg-gradients-to-display-varying-colors-relative-to-the-size-of-the-c). Do none of those help you?

Comment: Also, besides what @LarsKotthoff said, you should post an example you tried to pull this off, so that everyone could start from there.

Answer (score 12):

SVG does not allow for these kind of gradients. I've done something very similar before, I created a "donut chart" where each wedge is a different color:

```js
var arc, data, padding, steps = 2, r=400/2, pi = Math.PI;
    var padding = 2 * r / 200;
    arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(r-40)
      .outerRadius(r).startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle; })
      .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle; });

    data = d3.range(180).map(function(d, i) {
      i *= steps;
      return {
        startAngle: i * (pi / 180),
        endAngle: (i + 2) * (pi / 180),
        fill: d3.hsl(i, 1, .5).toString()
      };
    });

    d3.select("body")
      .insert('svg')
      .attr("width", r*2+padding)
      .attr("height", r*2+padding)
      .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ") rotate(90) scale(-1,1)")
        .selectAll('path')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('path').attr("d", arc)
          .attr("stroke-width", 1)
          .attr("stroke", function(d) { return d.fill;})
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; });
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```