# Radial gradients of arcs in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, radial-gradients

I see from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198252/d3-arc-gradient), how to make an arc in D3.js have a 1D gradient from one end of the arc to the other. I would also like to apply a radial gradient from the inner ring to the outer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [`radialGradient`](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_radial.asp). Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1110/).

Comment: Thanks Lars! Your answers are always on the money.