# d3js Pie chart gradient

Tags: d3.js, gradient, pie-chart

Have been trying to build a pie/donut chart with smooth gradient on it but figured out that it's quite difficult to make. Already spent a lot of time and still haven't any luck how to resolve that problem. I'm using d3js library

I have something similar to this

[image]

And want to fill it with gradient, exactly like this

[image]

Any advice how to make it more close to it. Maybe someone of you have already faced with that issue and have some knowledge about it.

Will be appreciate for any answers and advices.

Comment: I agree that this is not at all trivial (unless there turns out to be a SVG built-in way to do it, which I'm pretty sure there isn't). Even doing this in photoshop would be a challenge. The only way I can think of achieving this effect is to break up the arcs into a bunch of smaller arc segments with either solid fills or with linear gradients whose direction angle matches the arc's tangent angle. Doable, but not trivial.

Comment: You want a gradient on each "slice" or a gradient across the whole thing?

Comment: @Mark Yes, exactly across the whole pie, that smoothly overflows front one slice to another but has gaps between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @meetamit says in his comment, there's no built-in SVG way I can find to product a *circular* gradient like you show.  However, if we build on this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198252/d3-arc-gradient) we can replicate your chart pretty well.

The trick is to make a donut of 360 arcs (one for each degree) to create the gradient ourselves.  We can then use the `pie` calculation to not include the arcs where our slice padding should be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    
      // sample data
      var data = [10,20,30,40,50];
    
      var height = 500,
          width = 500,
          radius = 200,
          padding = 0.04;
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width/2 + ',' + width/2 + ')');
        
      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius);
      
      // pie the data
      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d; });
      data = pie(data);

      // create our gradient
      var colors = [],
          slice = 0,
          inPad = false;
      // 360 degrees
      d3.range(360).forEach(function(d, i) {
        // convert to radians
        var start = i * (Math.PI / 180),
            end = (i + 1) * (Math.PI / 180);
        // if we are in a padding area
        if ( Math.abs(data[slice].startAngle - start) < padding || 
            Math.abs(data[slice].endAngle - start) < padding ) {
          inPad = true;
        } else {
          // when to move to next slice
          if (inPad){
            // move to next slice
            slice++;
            // "stick" on last slice
            if (slice >= data.length) slice = 4;
          }
          inPad = false;
        }
        // only push if not in padding
        if (!inPad){
          colors.push({
            startAngle: start,
            endAngle: end,
            fill: d3.hsl(i, 1, .5).toString()
          });
        }
      });
      // add arcs
      svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(colors)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'arc')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .style('fill', function(d){
          return d.fill;
        })
        .style('stroke',function(d){
          return d.fill;
        });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```