# Change Legends and Node to an circle image

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm still new in D3.js , currently I had hand over with the project using D3.js.

May I ask about how to change the colour Scale to image ?
The Nodes and Legends is related, the Node color is based on Legends.

Here with my JSON.

```
"colourScale":"d3.scaleOrdinal().domain([\"Low\",\"Medium\",\"High\",\"Very High\"]).range([\"#009a44\",\"#eaaa00\",\"#f68d2e\",\"#bc204b\"]);",
```

and here with my Javascript

```
    // draw nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
     .style("fill", function(d) { 
     if(d['group']==='Low')
     {
     return "#009a44";
     }
     else if(d['group']==='Medium')
     {
     return "#eaaa00";
     }
     else if(d['group']==='High')
     {
     return "#f68d2e";
     }
     else{
      return "#bc204b"; 
     }

     })

      .style("opacity", options.opacity)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)

      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(drag);
```

Here with my screenshot of result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend you to read the [this documentation](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/custom_color.html) that could provide you with some insights on how to manage colors with d3.js.

Actually you have all the required information in your JSON. So firstly you should create your scale object. Here is an example using the data provided in your JSON.

```
var myData = ["Low","Medium","High","Very High"];

// Defining colors
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(myData)
  .range(["#009a44","#eaaa00","#f68d2e","#bc204b"]) // Your data
  .unknown('black') // Fallback solution
```

After that you should apply this object to your d3 structure in some similar manner:

```
d3
  ... // Here goes your svg structure creation
  .style('fill', function(d) { // Applying your original scale
    return color(d.group);
  });
```

Here you can find a complete example of your node graph with legend

```js
var myData = ["Low","Medium","High","Very High"];

var graph = {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 'Low'},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 'Low'},
    {"id": "Mlle", "group": 'Medium'},
    {"id": "Mme", "group": 'Medium'},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 'High'},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 'Very High'},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 'Very High'},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 'Random'},
  ],
  "links": [
  ]
}

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

// Defining colors
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(myData)
  .range(["#009a44","#eaaa00","#f68d2e","#bc204b"]) // Your data
  .unknown('black') // Fallback solution

var linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, myData.length - 1])
 .range([0, 100]);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    
  var circles = node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
  }

d3.select('#wrapper')
 .selectAll('text')
 .data(myData)
 .enter()
 .append('text')
 .attr('y', function(d, i) {
  return linearScale(i);
 })
 .text(function(d) {
  return d;
 })
 .style('fill', function(d) {
  return color(d);
 });
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600">
  <g id="wrapper" transform="translate(100, 40)">
   </g>
</svg>
```

Please, let me know if my answer is not clear for you or you need some additional information or help.

Comment: may I ask about how to change to gradient Color?

Comment: I think you can find a pretty detailed answer regarding gradient [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639290/d3js-pie-chart-gradient). Maybe you could provide me with some StackBlitz or whatever else code snipped so I could help you more effectively

Comment: My first example (https://codepen.io/sergey_mell/pen/JjogNxQ) seems to be right what you need for your legend. You just need to change the direction from horizontal to vertical and that's it.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah, I've updated my answer with more specific example which is close enough to your case. Please, take a look